# How to compare small changes made in the graph editor?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

If I make a small change in the graph editor, is there a way I can compare the change made from before and after I edit a channel in the 3D viewport? Like a before and after view or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just make a copy of the object/armature and parent it to an empty and move the empty aside:

[image]